# Redshift Hash Join - Casting Varchar as Text to FK when both same type?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a SQL statement that is JOINing some outer table on some inner table ON "somekey". Both the outer table's and inner table's "somekey" are exactly the same datatype - varchar(36). However, for some reason when analyzing the query plan, Redshift wants to cast each as text first. I imagine this might reduce performance. 1) Why is it casting? 2) Can I make it not cast? 3) Does it matter (does it actually hurt performance)?

The partial plan:

- XN Hash Join DS_DIST_ALL_NONE  (cost=64.17..2067242.11 rows=28074
  width=160)

  - Hash Cond: (("outer".somekey)::text =
    ("inner".somekey)::text)

Comment: what matters? dist key and sort key. and dist type of the smaller table. is this a big expensive join that you need to optimise? - dont think of redshift as being a transaction db. (no indexes - many table scans is the norm)